# How to open the chrome browser to a chrome dev tool url

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, terminal, google-chrome-devtools, v8

With the most recent version of node,

Typing `node --inspect ajavascriptfile.js`

Outputs a url for you to visit in your chrome browser, great!

(Documentation for V8 inspector [here](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_v8_inspector_integration_for_node_js))

But how can I open that url with my terminal?

I can open the browser for files or urls with:

`open -a Google\ Chrome ./path/to/file.html`

or

`open -a Google\ Chrome http://google.com`

But trying the same for the url:

`open -a Google\ Chrome chrome-devtools://devtools/remote/se...`

Gives me the error:

```
The file /Users/samhouston/proj/chrome-devtools:/devtools/remote/se... does not exist.
```

How can I get chrome to open its browser to this url through my terminal?

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`open` doesn't support the `chrome-devtools` protocol, so it just tries to open a local file path instead. Since it doesn't exist, it gives you the error you are getting.

I looked around for another solution and I found that you can use an `osascript` to tell the application itself to open the URL.

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome & osascript -e 'tell application "Google Chrome" to open location "chrome-devtools://devtools/remote/serve_file/@60cd6e859b9f557d2312f5bf532f6aec5f284980/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=localhost:9229/node"'
```

Comment: Thank you so much, was looking into creating a manifest file or something silly like that (totally the wrong route). Yours is a much simpler solution